# How to use verbosity level in your tests in Django

Tags: django, django-testing, django-unittest

Running a Django test case allows you to specify verbosity (0,1,2,3) like this

```
manage.py test -v 2 myapp.tests.test_mycode.TestMyCode.test_func
```

How can I receive the verbosity flag inside my `test_func`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `inspect` module:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import inspect

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def get_verbosity(self):
        for s in reversed(inspect.stack()):
            options = s[0].f_locals.get('options')
            if isinstance(options, dict):
                return int(options['verbosity'])
        return 1

    def test_func(self):
        verbosity = self.get_verbosity()
        self.assertEqual(verbosity, 2)
```

Comment: Well done. I'm surprised there's no straight forward option available when you inherit from `TestCase`

Comment: I suppose that `TestCase` doesn't intended to output anything so there is no reason to have `verbosity` attribute in it.